# npm publish will encode slash as %2f

Tags: node.js, npm, artifact

We have an Artifact where we put packages there,
but when I cd to my package folder and run `npm publish` it will end up with a 400 error:

`npm ERR! 400 Bad Request - PUT https://artifactrepository.company.net/artifactory/api/npm/npm-enterprise/@orgName%2fpackageName`

the slash is replaced by the encoded %2f, btw I can run npm install @orgName/packageName, there will be no problem with the slash, is there any workaround for this? since the Artifact services are not managed by us, we have no permission to modify it.

Comment: Have you tried manually making a PUT request using "/"?

Comment: it is hard to manually do this, but finally we set up a Jenkins job to uploaded it successfully, thx

Answer (score 0):

Setup for your Team in Packages access Read && Write instead of just Read permission on NPM site

Comment: it is not a permission problem I believe, but we resolved this by setting up a Jenkins job to upload